# How to achieve high performance of Spring Kafka Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How do I increase the performance of Kafka consumer ?I have(and need)  Atleast Once Kafka Consumer semantics

I have the below configuration.The processInDB() takes 2 minutes to complete .So just to process 10 messages(all in single partition)  its taking 20 minutes(assuming 2 minutes per message). I can call  processInDB in different thread but I can lose messages !.How can I process all 10 messages between  2 to 4 minutes window ?

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "grpid-mytopic120112141");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
  props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");

ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ValidatedConsumerClass> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
```

Below is my Kafka Consumer code.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "mytopic-3", concurrency = "6", groupId = "mytopic-1-groupid")
    public void consumeFromTopic1(@Payload @Valid ValidatedConsumerClass message, ConsumerRecordMetadata c)  {

        dbservice.processInDB(message);


    }
```

Comment: @RanLupovich i already have mutiple partition have it .i am talking increase processing speed when messages are in 1 partition

Comment: As you state the problem is within your db service , that it takes you 2 minutes to process the messages,  you can not parallel consume from the same partition  , on the same group, that would brake your in-partition order guaranty

Comment: You might want to change to working in batch mode and send the whole polled record in one-go to the database instead of round tripping for one row each time

Comment: @RanLupovich problem is not within DB service .It's expected to take 1-2 minutes as we are doing heavy process

Comment: You are processing in RECORD mode, in single partition you have 10 msgs , each msgs takes 2 minutes , the only solution IMHO is to switch to BATCH mode and parallel handling the polled records with threads , waiting for all the batch to end , then decide to continue or not... let's see what other might say

Comment: Yes, using a batch listener would help - you just need to hold up the consumer thread in the listener until all the individual records have completed processing. In the next release (2.8.0-M1 milestone released today) there is support for out-of-order manual acknowledgments where the framework defers the commits until the "gaps are filled" https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M1/reference/html/#x28-ooo-commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a batch listener would help - you just need to hold up the consumer thread in the listener until all the individual records have completed processing.

In the next release (2.8.0-M1 milestone released today) there is support for out-of-order manual acknowledgments where the framework defers the commits until the "gaps are filled" https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.0-M1/reference/html/#x28-ooo-commits

Comment: so you mean I just need to change  `AckMode.BATCH`.And How can i hold the listener thread .Can you provide pseodo code or hint..I found in one of your previous stackoverflow comment that using background can result in loss of messages

Comment: No that is just the mode for committing offsets; use a Batch Listener that consumes a `List<...>` instead of a single record. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#batch-listeners Use a `CountDownLatch` or similar set to the number of records in the list and wait on it in your listener and have each task count it down when processing is complete. I can add an example tomorrow if you need more clarification.

Comment: The framework can’t do validation on individual records. You have to move it up to your listener. It is generally better to add more partitions. Parallel processing from a single partition is difficult and causes many problems like these.

Comment: Then make sure that doesn’t happen on the producer side. 10 is obviously not enough if you need to explore multithreading for a singe partition. My advice… don’t do it.

Comment: `My advice… don’t do it.` You mean  not to use BATCH and Count Down Latch ?

Comment: I mean don’t try to process records from a single partition in parallel at all. If you do, you will have to deal with a lot of complexity around committing offsets, error handling, etc. It is much easier to to increase the partitions and let the container manage concurrency.

Comment: @GaryRussell it would be really helpful if you could point me to your example of a BatchListener with CountDownLatch implementation.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for; I suggest you ask a new question showing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion not purely related to spring kafka, as you stated in your tags that your also exploring the consumer api and not only spring kafka, so I am allowing to myself to suggest it here, you might want to test out this api

https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-confluent-parallel-message-processing-client/

https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

- its in alpha stage, so not recommended for production, but may keep an eye on that as well

But as stated in my earlier comments , you might just want to make more partitions